# Issue with dismissModalViewController

Tags: iphone, ios5, modalviewcontroller

I've got a problem when i dismiss a modal view:

I've got a tabBar with five tabs.
I'm on the fourth tab and i display a modal view.
When i dismiss it. I go on the first tab but i would like to stay on the fourth.

To show the modal I call this method, in the parent controller:

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

To hide the modal I call this method, in the parent controller:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I already try to call self.tabBarController/self.navigationController methods instead of self method but it's the same issue.

Someone has an idea?

EDIT:

I call the methods in the fourth tab's controller.

This is the context:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    imgPicker.delegate = self;
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0: {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kMobiglissFromPicker];
            imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kMobiglissFromPicker];
                imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
            }               
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imgPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *origin = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    UIImage *photo = [origin thumbnailImage:280
                          transparentBorder:0.0
                               cornerRadius:0.0
                       interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];

    [icon replaceImageWithImage:photo];

    [serverProxy updateProfileAvatar:photo];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imgPicker.delegate = nil;
}

- (IBAction)editAvatar:(id)sender {
    NSString *camera = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] ? [WPLanguage get:@"SignupPhotosheetCamera"] : nil;
    UIActionSheet *photoSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:[WPLanguage get:@"SignupPhotosheetTitle"]
                                                            delegate:self 
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:[WPLanguage get:@"CANCEL"] 
                                              destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                                   otherButtonTitles:[WPLanguage get:@"SignupPhotosheetGallery"], camera, nil];
    [photoSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: Please provide context for these calls, without seeing your code, it is impossible to tell what is going on. And I hope you are calling `presentModalViewController` within the view controller associated with the fourth tab and not within the view controller displaying the tab bar.

Comment: If your view controller presented by the fourth tab presented the modal view this problem would be solved. Or is that the case?

Comment: @gurooj I'm calling `presentModalViewController` within the view controller associated with the fourth tab.
@JoePasq the modal view is already presented by the fourth tab but when i dismiss it i go to the first tab and i would like to stay in the fourth

Comment: Nothing about the given code jumps out as blatantly incorrect. However, I hope you are using automatic reference counting, because all objects allocated must be released, or else you are creating memory leaks. Maybe that could be an issue? Either way, it needs to be addressed. And something about `imgPicker.delegate = nil` seems off to me. I've never used that, and I've never experienced any problems with Image Picker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess (you need to add more details): Does your viewController, which implements the `UITabBarDelegate`, set the selected item on `viewWillAppear:` (or one of the other methods called?

Comment: Thanks a lot it was the problem's origin.